# Keep batch file from waiting for completion of opened file[s]?

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I am making a Batch file to run a collection of AHK (AutoHotKey) script files, with the intent of placing in in my startup folder.

However I have run into a problem when executing the batch file, it only starts the first script and then pauses, presumably waiting for the script to finish, which it never will (due to the nature of AHK scripts).  How can I get it to continue on without waiting for one file to be finished?

I figure this is probably a simple issue as I am not super swift with batch files yet, but I couldn't find anything with some googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Starting a Program

See `start /?` and `call /?` for help on all three ways.

### Specify a program name

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### Use Start command

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

### Use Call command

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.